# Does n't gradle have its own repository in the way Maven has m2?

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-3

Gradle always seems to use maven m2 repository. Does n't it have an equivalent of m2?

Comment: Do you mean https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html ?

Comment: @JFMeier Is that m2's equivalent? Without using m2 or some other build tool's repository at all, can gradle work?

Answer (score 0):

Gradle can consume dependencies in different layouts, including Maven, Ivy, Flat directory structures and absolute file locations. So it doesn't always use a Maven repository as you say.

When it downloads external dependencies, it caches them in `$HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2`. This is partly what the `.m2` is about, but the Gradle one is just a cache and things will be wiped from it after having been unused for a while.

You are also not supposed to use the Gradle cache directory as a local repository for sharing SNAPSHOT versions between projects during development, like you would with `.m2`. If you need to to this, Gradle can work with a local `.m2` repository. Just declare:

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}
```

And you can consume and publish artifacts to the local `.m2` folder, just like Maven would do.

There are also other ways to produce and consume local artifacts in Gradle, including [multi-projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) and [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html), that are sometimes better suited than going through the `.m2` repository.